# Using variance components of a mixed model to obtain Std. Error of a coef from an OLS model (in R)

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, standard-error

In the famous [hsb dataset](https://github.com/rnorouzian/e/blob/master/hsb.csv) (students nested in schools; DV: `math`), suppose we fit 3 models:

1. Ignoring the level 2 clustering (`sch.id`). Below, I ran a simple model called `ols1` that uses a binary cluster-level predictor (`sector`) in this model.
2. Ignoring the level 1 data and just using the average of each cluster as DV. Below, I ran a simple model called `ols2` that uses a binary cluster-level predictor (`sector`) in this model.
3. Fitting a mixed-effects model that takes `sch.id` as a random-effect and uses `sector` as a predictor (`m1`).

From `m1` alone, it is easy to find the **Std. Error** of `sector` coefficient in `ols1` model because: `sigma(ols1)^2` (****sigma^2 in blue***) almost equals 6.68 ($\tau_{00}$) + 39.15 ($\sigma_{e}^2$) (i.e., variance components) from `m1`.

[image]

where $n$ is the average cluster sample size, $J$ is the number of clusters, and $\sigma_{sector}$ is the variance of the `sector` predictor.

**Question:** How can we obtain **Std. Error** of sector coefficient in `ols2` using variance components in `m1`?

```
library(lme4)
library(tidyverse)

hsb <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/hsb.csv')
hsb_ave <- hsb %>% group_by(sch.id) %>% mutate(math_ave = mean(math)) %>% slice(1)

ols1 <- lm(math ~ sector, data = hsb) #!# Notice `Std. Error` for `sector` is `0.1589`. #!#
summary(ols1)$coef

ols2 <- lm(math_ave ~ sector, data = hsb_ave) # How to estimate `sector` `Std. Error` for 
                                              # THIS model from `m1` variance components?
summary(ols2)$coef

m1 <- lmer(math ~ sector + (1|sch.id), data = hsb)
summary(m1)
```

Comment: (+1) It's an interesting question that requires some thought. What is the motivation behind this ?

Comment: @RobertLong, thanks Robert. At its core, the question is asking: *"Is the between-cluster variation (i.e., $\tau_{00}$) in a two-level nested mixed-effects model (i.e., `m1`), the same as the amount of **total variation** that we would otherwise get if we only use the cluster-level data in a NON-HLM, regular regression model (i.e., `ols2`)?"* It helps if you could also clarify what is the formula for $SE$ of the cluster-level predictor `sector` coefficient in `ols2` model? In `ols1` answer to these questions is clear as I demonstrate both above. But I don't know the answers for `ols2`.